# Getter method for services in Symfony controller

Tags: symfony

Is it a good practice to have a service getter for frequently used services in a controller? For example I mean:

```
class SomeController Extends Contorller {

      private function getSomethingManager()
      {
           return $this->get('myvendorname.something.manager');
      }

}
```

Comment: By MVC pattern you should put all logic of working with DB in models.

Comment: @Dmytro Huz Well, I chose example poorly. You are absolutely right, I don't want any Database logic in my controller, I just typed the most common/most used service name I got in my mind, and that was actually the doctrine entity manager.

Comment: ah...I guess I understood you. You ask about is it good to create a method getting service which you use very often in that controller. 
I think it depends on two things:
1) If you are using it only in that controller - it is pretty correct. It is DRY principle.
2) But if you use it very often in many controllers so just put this getter in some 'helper' class and just call it whenever you need ;)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean to ask. I use this service quite often in this one controller, and I thought it is easier to '$this->getMyService()' than '$this->get('vendorname_bundlename.long_service_name.manager')'. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a bit confusing because you can use the Doctrine service directly with your controller. You can inject it in your Action if you use the Autowire function.

```
public function test(EntityManagerInterface $em) {

}
```

Then you have the entity manager injected or you can load it over the controller with:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
```

So this is not a real good example. When you use [autowire](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html) all classes are registered as service and you can use it.

For database queries you have to use entities and repositories.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are above Symfony 3.3 you can use a [Service Locater](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/5oex/fetching-services-with-a-service-locator-service-in-symfony-applications). You list all common services in Service Locator class. When you need to fetch a specific service from anywhere (from example, Controller, Command, Service so on), all you have to do is, inject `ServiceLocator` class and fetch required service via `ServiceLocator:locate`.

It is pretty simple and useful. It helps you to reduce dependency injection as well. Have a look at the full example in the link above.

```
class ServiceLocator implements ServiceLocatorInterface, ServiceSubscriberInterface
{
    private $locator;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $locator)
    {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedServices()
    {
        return [
            ModelFactoryInterface::class,
            CalculatorUtilInterface::class,
            EntityManagerInterface::class,
            AnotherClass::class,
            AndAnother::class,
        ];
    }

    public function get(string $id)
    {
        if (!$this->locator->has($id)) {
            throw new ServiceLocatorException(sprintf(
                'The entry for the given "%s" identifier was not found.',
                $id
            ));
        }

        try {
            return $this->locator->get($id);
        } catch (ContainerExceptionInterface $e) {
            throw new ServiceLocatorException(sprintf(
                'Failed to fetch the entry for the given "%s" identifier.',
                $id
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how you use it: `ServiceLocator->locate(AnotherClass::class);`